# When a door is widely open, what words do we use?

Tags: vocabulary

When a door is opened partly it seems correct to choose the word "ajar". If the door is widely open, which words are correct to use? For example, can "broad" be used?

Comment: Why not just use [wide-open](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wide-open)? Also, if a door metaphorically invites someone to enter, one may use _gaping_. I don't think, however, that studying such a rare word would be necessary for an average language learner.

Comment: To me as a native speaker, "widely open" takes a moment to understand, because "widely" is almost always used in the abstract. "This is widely known", "It is widely agreed", "Our opinions are widely different". It's generally not used as the adverb form of "wide" in the physical sense.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. If you look up a dictionary, it will tell you that *broad* means wide in extent or scope. This implies that it is usually used with abstract concepts such as a project or one's knowledge.

My best suggestion here is what bytebuster said: **wide-open**. There are also less common terms like **agape** (when used predicatively) or **gaping** (when used attributively), although gaping usually refers to the open space created by the wide-open door than the door itself. I do, however, suggest you to follow bytebuster's advice unless you are composing serious texts.

Comment: Your "broad" usage is very uncommon. NGrams for [inches](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=inches+broad%2Cinches+wide&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) and [yards broad](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=yards+broad%2Cyards+wide&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=) show that nearly everyone uses **wide** in such constructions.

Comment: It is quite a dated expression. You can find examples of it on Google Books. Take a look at this: http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=11RIAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA258&dq=%226+feet+broad%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ei=1o0mUd6FNKrPmgWK5YCICQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%226%20feet%20broad%22&f=false

Comment: You're not kidding it's "quite dated". I set the date range in my NGram links there to 1900-2000 - you have to go back a couple of centuries to find "broad" being as common as "wide" in such constructions! I think ELL should stick to "reasonably current" usage as a rule.

Comment: OK. I removed the part about this. I just wanted to list out all the possible uses of the word. No harm meant. Was just trying to help, mate.

Comment: agape was the first word that came to my mind so you get my vote.

Comment: @James: I didn't intend to sound *that* critical! After all, your point saying "broad" is *usually used with abstract concepts* is absolutely spot-on! I don't agree with bytebuster's comment, insofar as I don't think "broad" is a "rare" word. But it's not well suited to describing either the width of a door, or the extent to which it's open. Anyway, following your edit, I think it's a truly excellent answer (and since it currently has 9 upvotes, you should get a [badge](http://ell.stackexchange.com/badges/23/nice-answer) when I add mine in a tick! :)

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, *The door was wide-open* means that the door was completely open in a physical sense.  However, when converted to *My/his door is wide-open,*  the expression often becomes idiomatic, meaning "People should always feel free to talk to\approach me/him". (This idiom might only pertain to North America English.)

As well, I am quite sure that *gaping* always refers adjectivally to a *gap* or *opening* in something that **is not (usually) meant to gape/be opened**.  For example, *There was a gaping hole in his parachute* -- there wasn't supposed to be a hole.  Similarly, the verb *gape* is typically used to mean *stare*, both of which refer to a kind of *looking at* that isn't supposed to happen (i.e., *I couldn't help gaping at Princess Diana as she walked along the street*; for the verbs *gape/stare*, to do so is socially-unacceptable/impolite--but as Hillary Mantel has recently [pointed out](http://www.lrb.co.uk/v35/n04/hilary-mantel/royal-bodies), irresistible.

Comment: As shown by [this NGram](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=my+door+is+wide+open%2Cmy+door+is+always+open&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=), the "idiomatic" usage is *My door is **always** open*, not *My door is **wide** open*, when the sense is *I am accessible*.

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe it is only in Canada that the two expressions are interchangeable for the idiomatic meaning.

Comment: I've occasionally been surprised to find what I thought was common usage among *all* Anglophones turns out to be SE UK specific. But I also think *always* is semantically more apt (so if both were commonly used by others around me, I'd still probably *always* use *always* myself! :)